# Identifying erroneous field in kubernetes deployment spec in C#-client

Tags: .net, kubernetes

I am trying to define a deployment spec using the C#-client of Kubernetes. The values of the fields of my spec are produced by some other application. As such, the deployment sometimes fails and I get an `Unprocessable entity`(Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException) error. However, it is really hard to identify which field results in the Unprocessable entity error.

Can someone tell me how I could get identify the erroneous field?

Here's the trace:

```
Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'UnprocessableEntity'
   at k8s.Kubernetes.CreateNamespacedDeploymentWithHttpMessagesAsync(V1Deployment body, String namespaceParameter, String dryRun, String fieldManager, String pretty, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.KubernetesExtensions.CreateNamespacedDeploymentAsync(IKubernetes operations, V1Deployment body, String namespaceParameter, String dryRun, String fieldManager, String pretty, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.KubernetesExtensions.CreateNamespacedDeployment(IKubernetes operations, V1Deployment body, String namespaceParameter, String dryRun, String fieldManager, String pretty)
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get a more detailed error by printing out the Response.Content field of the Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException.

```
try
{
    // Code for deployment
}
catch(Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Response.Content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the Kubernetes requests go through the [`kube-apiserver`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/).  The deployment spec needs to comply with the API spec documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#deployment-v1-apps).

You can start by looking at the kube-apiserver logs. You can also work your way backwards if you have a working deployment (Do you have a deployment YAML manifest file?). For example, you can try removing some fields from the YAML manifest of the deployment then run `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` to see if you can reproduce the error.